# No WiFi in Kubuntu on laptop with MEDIATEK MT7922 card (ASUS ROG Strix G17 2023 G713PI-LL028)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kubuntu, mediatek

I have an issue with my fresh laptop, it has MEDIATEK MT7922 WiFi card. I'm using double boot (Windows + Kubuntu), but I see no WiFi connection in Kubuntu at all (mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: hardware init failed), in Windows all works fine. Firstly I tried 22.04 release, saw this issue, found and read article that possible resolution in old kernel <5.16, but as I recall it has 5.18 "out of box", so I decided to install the latest 23.04. It came with 6.2.0-20-generic kernel, but  the same issue is still there. I see not only I have similar issue, but I don't quite not get how to resolve it.

First of all the "Fastboot" is disabled in the BIOS (I saw it as a possible issue)

Hibernation is also disabled in Windows.

Hold power button for 60 seconds, to possibly "hard" or "cold" reboot laptop. Not sure how it's properly must be done.

UPD: I found something interesting, but doesn't know what to do with it.

[image]

Here are some details about the system and the error:

```
arthur@rog:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: 08:bf:b8:2b:99:34
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-20-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:25 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcd04000-fcd04fff memory:fcd00000-fcd03fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=mt7921e latency=0
       resources: irq:102 memory:fca00000-fcafffff memory:fcb00000-fcb07fff

arthur@rog:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:0616]
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e0df]
        Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
        Kernel modules: mt7921e
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:242a] (rev 01)

 arthur@rog:~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep mt7921e
2023-06-11T22:23:11.206338+03:00 rog kernel: [    6.439473] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 1) timeout
2023-06-11T22:23:11.206358+03:00 rog kernel: [    6.439485] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
2023-06-11T22:23:14.534340+03:00 rog kernel: [    9.767483] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 2) timeout
2023-06-11T22:23:14.534359+03:00 rog kernel: [    9.767491] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
2023-06-11T22:23:17.862322+03:00 rog kernel: [   13.095794] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 3) timeout
2023-06-11T22:23:17.862340+03:00 rog kernel: [   13.095801] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
2023-06-11T22:23:21.190337+03:00 rog kernel: [   16.423822] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 4) timeout
2023-06-11T22:23:21.190357+03:00 rog kernel: [   16.423830] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
2023-06-11T22:23:24.518309+03:00 rog kernel: [   19.751474] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 5) timeout
2023-06-11T22:23:24.518325+03:00 rog kernel: [   19.751485] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
2023-06-11T22:23:27.846330+03:00 rog kernel: [   23.079810] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 6) timeout
2023-06-11T22:23:27.846349+03:00 rog kernel: [   23.079817] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
2023-06-11T22:23:31.174293+03:00 rog kernel: [   26.407472] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 7) timeout
2023-06-11T22:23:31.174300+03:00 rog kernel: [   26.407483] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
2023-06-11T22:23:34.502328+03:00 rog kernel: [   29.735457] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 8) timeout
2023-06-11T22:23:34.502345+03:00 rog kernel: [   29.735466] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
2023-06-11T22:23:37.830332+03:00 rog kernel: [   33.063486] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 9) timeout
2023-06-11T22:23:37.830351+03:00 rog kernel: [   33.063498] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
2023-06-11T22:23:41.158308+03:00 rog kernel: [   36.391450] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 10) timeout
2023-06-11T22:23:41.158325+03:00 rog kernel: [   36.391457] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
2023-06-11T22:23:41.238297+03:00 rog kernel: [   36.471989] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: hardware init failed

arthur@rog:~$ sudo inxi -Faz
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic
    root=UUID=1a509298-47bc-42ee-814b-94e174316c34 ro quiet splash
    vt.handoff=7
  Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.4 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM Distro: Ubuntu 23.04
    (Lunar Lobster)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ROG Strix G713PI_G713PI v: 1.0
    serial: <filter>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: G713PI v: 1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI: American
    Megatrends LLC. v: G713PI.316 date: 04/17/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 76.7 Wh (83.9%) condition: 91.4/90.0 Wh (101.5%)
    volts: 17.4 min: 15.9 model: AS3GWAF3KC GA50358 type: Unknown
    serial: <filter> status: charging
CPU:
  Info: model: AMD Ryzen 9 7945HX with Radeon Graphics socket: FL1 bits: 64
    type: MT MCP arch: Zen 4 gen: 5 level: v4 note: check built: 2022
    process: TSMC n5 (5nm) family: 0x19 (25) model-id: 0x61 (97) stepping: 2
    microcode: 0xA601203
  Topology: cpus: 1x cores: 16 tpc: 2 threads: 32 smt: enabled cache:
    L1: 1024 KiB desc: d-16x32 KiB; i-16x32 KiB L2: 16 MiB desc: 16x1024 KiB
    L3: 64 MiB desc: 2x32 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1812 high: 2500 min/max: 1500/5459 boost: enabled
    base/boost: 2500/5450 scaling: driver: acpi-cpufreq governor: schedutil
    volts: 1.3 V ext-clock: 100 MHz cores: 1: 1500 2: 2500 3: 2500 4: 1500
    5: 1500 6: 1500 7: 1500 8: 1500 9: 2500 10: 1500 11: 1500 12: 1500
    13: 2500 14: 1500 15: 1500 16: 1500 17: 1500 18: 1500 19: 1500 20: 1500
    21: 1500 22: 2500 23: 1500 24: 1500 25: 1500 26: 1500 27: 2500 28: 2500
    29: 1500 30: 2500 31: 2500 32: 2500 bogomips: 159703
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
  Vulnerabilities:
  Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected
  Type: l1tf status: Not affected
  Type: mds status: Not affected
  Type: meltdown status: Not affected
  Type: mmio_stale_data status: Not affected
  Type: retbleed status: Not affected
  Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via
    prctl
  Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer
    sanitization
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Retpolines, IBPB: conditional, IBRS_FW,
    STIBP: always-on, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS: Not affected
  Type: srbds status: Not affected
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA AD106M [GeForce RTX 4070 Max-Q / Mobile]
    vendor: ASUSTeK GN21-X6 driver: nvidia v: 525.105.17
    alternate: nvidiafb,nouveau,nvidia_drm non-free: N/A
    status: unknown device ID pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 8 ports:
    active: none empty: DP-4, DP-5, HDMI-A-1, eDP-2 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:2860 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: AMD Raphael vendor: ASUSTeK driver: amdgpu v: kernel
    arch: RDNA-2 code: Navi-2x process: TSMC n7 (7nm) built: 2020-22 pcie:
    gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1,DP-2,DP-3
    bus-ID: 08:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:164e class-ID: 0300 temp: 59.0 C
  Device-3: IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 3-1:2 chip-ID: 13d3:5458 class-ID: fe01 serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
    compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 2560x1440 s-dpi: 98 s-size: 665x374mm (26.18x14.72")
    s-diag: 763mm (30.04")
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 mapped: eDP model: MNH301CA3-1 built: 2022 res: 2560x1440
    hz: 240 dpi: 171 gamma: 1.2 size: 381x214mm (15x8.43") diag: 437mm (17.2")
    ratio: 16:9 modes: max: 2560x1440 min: 640x480
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.2 renderer: AMD Radeon Graphics (gfx1036
    LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.49 6.2.0-20-generic) direct-render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie:
    gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:22bd
    class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_rpl_pci_acp6x v: kernel
    alternate: snd_pci_acp3x,snd_rn_pci_acp3x,snd_pci_acp5x,snd_pci_acp6x,snd_acp_pci,snd_pci_ps,snd_sof_amd_renoir,snd_sof_amd_rembrandt
    pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 08:00.5 chip-ID: 1022:15e2
    class-ID: 0480
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 08:00.6 chip-ID: 1022:15e3 class-ID: 0403
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.0-20-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: gen: 1 speed: 2.5 GT/s
    lanes: 1 port: e000 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: MEDIATEK MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Foxconn driver: mt7921e v: kernel pcie: gen: 2 speed: 5 GT/s
    lanes: 1 bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 14c3:0616 class-ID: 0280
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 3-2:3 chip-ID: 0489:e0f6 class-ID: e001 serial: <filter>
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: no
    address: <filter>
  Info: acl-mtu: 0:0 sco-mtu: 0:0 link-mode: peripheral accept
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 10.09 GiB (1.1%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 maj-min: 259:0 vendor: Micron model: 2400 MTFDKBA1T0QFM
    size: 953.87 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 63.2 Gb/s
    lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: V3MA003 temp: 33.9 C scheme: GPT
  SMART: yes health: PASSED on: 9d 3h cycles: 244
    read-units: 4,625,012 [2.36 TB] written-units: 5,367,133 [2.74 TB]
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 102.54 GiB size: 100.87 GiB (98.37%) used: 9.74 GiB (9.7%)
    fs: ext2 block-size: 4096 B dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3 maj-min: 259:3
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 100 MiB size: 96 MiB (96.00%)
    used: 63.1 MiB (65.8%) fs: vfat block-size: 512 B dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
    maj-min: 259:1
  ID-3: /home raw-size: 151.37 GiB size: 147.93 GiB (97.73%)
    used: 295.1 MiB (0.2%) fs: ext4 block-size: 4096 B dev: /dev/nvme0n1p4
    maj-min: 259:4
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 67.1 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 59.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0
Info:
  Processes: 481 Uptime: 1m wakeups: 3 Memory: 30.96 GiB used: 2.01 GiB (6.5%)
  Init: systemd v: 252 target: graphical (5) default: graphical
  tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: N/A Packages: 1902 pm: dpkg pkgs: 1895
  libs: 993 tools: apt,apt-get,aptitude pm: snap pkgs: 7 Shell: Sudo (sudo)
  v: 1.9.13p1 default: Bash v: 5.2.15 running-in: konsole inxi: 3.3.25




arthur@rog:/lib/firmware/mediatek$ ls -lah
total 21M
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  12K чер  4 11:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 91 root root  36K чер  4 11:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 498K чер  4 11:45 BT_RAM_CODE_MT7902_1_1_hdr.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 516K чер  4 11:45 BT_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1_1_hdr.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 518K тра  5 12:57 BT_RAM_CODE_MT7961_1_2_hdr.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  79K тра  5 12:57 mt7610e.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  79K тра  5 12:57 mt7610u.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 120K тра  5 12:57 mt7615_cr4.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 448K тра  5 12:57 mt7615_n9.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  11K тра  5 12:57 mt7615_rom_patch.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 294K тра  5 12:57 mt7622_n9.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  77K тра  5 12:57 mt7622pr2h.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  81K тра  5 12:57 mt7622_rom_patch.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 374K тра  5 12:57 mt7650e.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  90K тра  5 12:57 mt7662u.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  21K тра  5 12:57 mt7662u_rom_patch.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 328K тра  5 12:57 mt7663_n9_rebb.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 432K тра  5 12:57 mt7663_n9_v3.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 273K тра  5 12:57 mt7663pr2h.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 205K тра  5 12:57 mt7663pr2h_rebb.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 167K тра  5 12:57 mt7668pr2h.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3,5K тра  5 12:57 mt7915_eeprom.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3,5K тра  5 12:57 mt7915_eeprom_dbdc.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 142K тра  5 12:57 mt7915_rom_patch.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K тра  5 12:57 mt7915_wa.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,3M тра  5 12:57 mt7915_wm.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,0K тра  5 12:57 mt7916_eeprom.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 8,5K тра  5 12:57 mt7916_rom_patch.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 496K тра  5 12:57 mt7916_wa.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,7M тра  5 12:57 mt7916_wm.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,0K тра  5 12:57 mt7986_eeprom_mt7975_dual.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,0K тра  5 12:57 mt7986_eeprom_mt7976.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,0K тра  5 12:57 mt7986_eeprom_mt7976_dbdc.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,0K тра  5 12:57 mt7986_eeprom_mt7976_dual.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  13K тра  5 12:57 mt7986_rom_patch.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  13K тра  5 12:57 mt7986_rom_patch_mt7975.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 507K тра  5 12:57 mt7986_wa.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2,2M тра  5 12:57 mt7986_wm.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2,2M тра  5 12:57 mt7986_wm_mt7975.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2,4M тра  5 12:57 mt7986_wo_0.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2,4M тра  5 12:57 mt7986_wo_1.bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K чер  4 11:40 mt8173
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K чер  4 11:40 mt8183
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K чер  4 11:40 mt8186
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K чер  4 11:40 mt8192
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K чер  4 11:40 mt8195
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K чер  4 11:40 sof
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K чер  4 11:40 sof-tplg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 116K чер  4 11:45 WIFI_MT7902_patch_mcu_1_1_hdr.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 135K чер  4 11:45 WIFI_MT7922_patch_mcu_1_1_hdr.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  91K тра  5 12:57 WIFI_MT7961_patch_mcu_1_2_hdr.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 693K чер  4 11:45 WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7902_1.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 734K чер  4 11:45 WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 703K тра  5 12:57 WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7961_1.bin
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Please see: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20230614063252.1650824-1-kai.heng.feng@canonical.com/T/ It says: "When "Pre-boot WiFi" is enabled in BIOS, the mt7921e device may not work" Is this possibly the case for you?

Comment: Hi guys, waltinator unfortunately no :(
@chili555 yes, it's the same issue as I see, but I'm not sure what a solution there, for me it's looks like some code commits in git with comments, what it does mean? Is there a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there some setting in the BIOS that says 'Pre-Boot WiFi' or similar? Please check and reverse it.

Comment: Hi @chili555 There is exist BIOS setting to entirely disable the WiFi module, like security measures, set of options like "disable wireless, disable USB, webcam and etc", I tried all variations of it already, but it doesn't solve my issue, and there is nothing about "Pre-boot or Pre-Load WiFi".

Comment: Hi @chili555 I found additional bug info during boot-up, maybe it will reveal some additional details? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I bought a USB WiFI dongle (named Dual band AC600) in a desperate try to solve an issue in a different way... And it sees WiFi networks but is not able to connect to neither WiFi :(((

Comment: I expect that the USB won't connect because of the conflicting mt7921e driver. Try blacklisting it and try again. I have researched this issue extensively and I don't see a solution for "Failed to get patch semaphore." I suggest that you file a bug report and use the USB until there is a fix. Sorry.